# Crop image from camera and save it

Tags: android, image, camera, save, crop

I have this class where I take a picture and save it without problems. If possible< I want to add the ability to crop after the picture was taken. I did some research but I not been able to find what I need. I don't understand how I can save a cropped image. I saw some examples but no one gave the answer I was looking for.  All of them just take a picture, crop, and show it in a ImageView.

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "CallCamera";
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ = 0;

    private Uri fileUri = null;
    private ImageView photoImage = null;
    private String fileName = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = getOutputPhotoFile();
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile());
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(i,
                Constantes.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    private File getOutputPhotoFile() {
        File directory = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        fileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        return new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constantes.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri photoUri = null;
                if (data == null) {
                    photoUri = fileUri;
                    setDataPhoto(photoUri);
                } else {
                    photoUri = data.getData();
                    setDataPhoto(photoUri);
                }
            } 
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void setDataPhoto(Uri photoUri) {
        String filePath = photoUri.getPath();
        fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Constantes.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);
        intent.putExtra(Constantes.IMAGE_NAME, fileName);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably, you will find the _crop image_ ***intent*** useful. See a short [_tutorial_](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/capture-images-and-crop-images-using.html) where capture and crop intents work together.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bitmap. You can convert your photo to Bitmap easily using BitmapFactory. It can create bitmap from file paths, byte arrays etc. Have a look at [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).

Then you can crop it the way you want. After you convert the photo to bitmap, you have to use the method;

```
Bitmap dest=Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Here x and y are coordinates of starting points, that are the bottom-left parts. Beware that the width and height you enter cannot be larger than the original bitmap's dimensions.